# Java Spring, when temp multipart file gets deleted?

Tags: java, spring, threadpool, multipartform-data, java-threads

I have a spring application, I have an endpoint which accept multiple files, so you can upload multiple files.
I'm trying to make it work faster by utilizing threads, so what I did is I created a ThreadPool and tried to process each file async (in a different thread).
Actually I found a tutorial on youtube which is doing almost what I want and I wanted to try his code and see it works or not, but it didn't work for me either.
this is the link of the tutorial.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rJBLFA95Io
I believe he doesn't get the error because in his case always number of files and thread match.
What I found out is if number of tasks in my pool are equal or less than number of available threads then every thing works perfectly fine, but if number of tasks or greater than number of available threads I get an error which is this :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /private/var/folders/41/81526n295q1cptcb1tbrs544h504m8/T/tomcat.9191.5294201821824312569/work/Tomcat/localhost/ROOT/upload_ff67c7fe_2f2f_44c6_8eb9_3250c8a8739b_00000003.tmp (No such file or directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.getInputStream(DiskFileItem.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPart.getInputStream(ApplicationPart.java:100) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile.getInputStream(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:251) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at com.mhndev.springexecutor.service.UserService.parseCSVFile(UserService.java:47) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.mhndev.springexecutor.service.UserService.saveUsers(UserService.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.mhndev.springexecutor.service.UserService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c14fedc2.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.lambda$doSubmit$3(AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.java:278) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1768) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

So what I suspect is when a task remains in the pool the multipart file gets deleted before the task can have a assigned thread for some reason.

my controller :

```java
package com.mhndev.springexecutor.controller;

import com.mhndev.springexecutor.entity.User;
import com.mhndev.springexecutor.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/users", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity saveUsers(@RequestParam(value = "files") MultipartFile[] files) throws Exception {
        for(MultipartFile file: files) {
            userService.saveUsers(file);
        }

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).build();
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/users", produces = "application/json")
    public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity> findAllUsers() {
        return userService.findAllUsers().thenApply(ResponseEntity::ok);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/getUsersByThread", produces = "application/json")
    public  ResponseEntity getUsers(){
        CompletableFuture<List<User>> users1=userService.findAllUsers();
        CompletableFuture<List<User>> users2=userService.findAllUsers();
        CompletableFuture<List<User>> users3=userService.findAllUsers();
        CompletableFuture.allOf(users1,users2,users3).join();
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
    }
}
```

and my service:

```java
package com.mhndev.springexecutor.service;

import com.mhndev.springexecutor.entity.User;
import com.mhndev.springexecutor.repository.UserRepository;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserService.class);

    @Async("taskExecutor")
    public CompletableFuture<List<User>> saveUsers(MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<User> users = parseCSVFile(file);
        logger.info("saving list of users of size {}, thread name : {}", users.size(), "" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        users = repository.saveAll(users);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        logger.info("Total time {}", (end - start));
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(users);
    }

    @Async("taskExecutor")
    public CompletableFuture<List<User>> findAllUsers(){
        logger.info("get list of user by " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        List<User> users = repository.findAll();
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(users);
    }

    private List<User> parseCSVFile(final MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
        final List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            try (final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream()))) {
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    final String[] data = line.split(",");
                    final User user = new User();
                    user.setName(data[0]);
                    user.setEmail(data[1]);
                    user.setGender(data[2]);
                    users.add(user);
                }
                return users;
            }
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            logger.error("Failed to parse CSV file", e);
            throw new Exception("Failed to parse CSV file {}", e);
        }
    }

}
```

and configuration for threadpool:

```java
package com.mhndev.springexecutor.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfig {

    @Bean(name = "taskExecutor")
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(3);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(3);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("User-Thread-");
        executor.initialize();

        return executor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Temporary data is the request bound. Source -> [MultipartFile Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html)

Comment: @WildDev so in that case why I get this error ? Is it related to how different threads have access to the file system ? Is it because temp files are accessible for only one thread ? so what is the problem and what should I do ? Any hint that help me to start moving forward with more tests and inspections are welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: Since you use `@Async` methods the http request completes before the actual file is processed. So the file is not exists when another thread refers to it. You have to read the file contents first, use another file accessor just like  `MultipartFile.getBytes()` to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by using the CompletableFuture.
so I changed my controller as follow :

```java
    @PostMapping(value = "/users", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity saveUsers(@RequestParam(value = "files") MultipartFile[] files) throws Exception {
         var res = new ArrayList<CompletableFuture<List<User>>>();
        for(MultipartFile file: files) {
            res.add(userService.saveUsers(file));
        }

        for(CompletableFuture<List<User>> item: res) {
            System.out.println(item.get().size());
        }

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).build();
    }
```

it seems request's session is over and then temp file is deleted after request's session is over.
you know how I figured out ? I added a sleep in the controller body and it worked so I made sure that it is because request is over but there are some unfinished tasks in the queue of thread pool and controller doesn't wait for tasks to be completed, and it seems that I had to use compltable future.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a year since you posted but here's an alternative to your problem. It may be that someone has been through it and has not found a way out.

You can save the MultipartFile to a file in a directory. Here's code for that:

```
public List<Path> saveFile(MultipartFile[] files) {

    List<Path> files = new ArrayList<>();

    for(MultipartFile file: files) {

        try {

            Path root = Paths.get(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "/upload/");
            Files.createDirectories(root);
            Path filePath = this.root.resolve(""file.getOriginalFilename());

            Files.delete(filePath);
            Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), filePath);

            files.add(filePath)

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e instanceof FileAlreadyExistsException) {
                throw new RuntimeException("A file of that name already exists.");
            }

            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    return files;
}
```

After saving you work with the saved file and not with the MultipartFile

```
@PostMapping(value = "/users", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity saveUsers(@RequestParam(value = "files") MultipartFile[] files) throws Exception {

    var res = new ArrayList<CompletableFuture<List<User>>>();
     
    List<Path> pathFiles = saveFile(files);
     
    for(Path file: pathFiles) {
        res.add(userService.saveUsers(file));
    }

    for(CompletableFuture<List<User>> item: res) {
        System.out.println(item.get().size());
    }

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).build();
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of your code. It's a bit hard to understand what it's doing right now.

Answer (score 0):

Multipart fields in any POJO object when used in CompletableFuture store the file in a temporary directory, but when accessing the file, it can't find temp directory  and hence the exception file not found.

**Solution:**

Implemented a `HashMap<String,byte[]>` and stored the `bytes[]` before calling `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() - { //Business Logic Implementation })`

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents on this problem.
Both [@Majid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695427/majid-abdolhosseini) and [@Giovani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22191575/giovani-priori)'s answers had an issue.

**ISSUE**: A response will not be given till all the Files have been processed.

I think this defeats the purpose of Async.

[I am still not sure why MultipartFile cant be read from a reused thread. (please tell if you find out)]

---

I solved above issue with:

1. read multipart file from rest call
2. save a temp file copy in current directory
3. give file obj to thread
4. thread will read and store data in h2 db **asynchronously**
5. thread will delete the temp file

PS: *same can be achieved by saving MultiPart file in cache or db*

---

**Logs** : (Notice "**[INFO] - Done processing - sending response back**" is called and threads keep working asynchronously afterwards)

```
[INFO] - storing files
[INFO] -  -- saving file MOCK_DATA.csv
[INFO] -  -- saving file MOCK_DATA (1).csv
[INFO] -  -- saving file MOCK_DATA (2).csv
[INFO] - userThread-1 > processing file MOCK_DATA.csv
[INFO] -   > parsing csv file MOCK_DATA.csv of size 62582 
[INFO] - Done processing - sending response back
[INFO] - userThread-2 > processing file MOCK_DATA (1).csv
[INFO] -   > parsing csv file MOCK_DATA (1).csv of size 62414 
[INFO] - userThread-1  > saved all 1000 users
[INFO] - userThread-2  > saved all 1000 users
[INFO] - userThread-1  > total users : 2001
[INFO] - userThread-1 > deleting file : MOCK_DATA.csv
[INFO] - >Thread is free userThread-1
[INFO] - userThread-1 > processing file MOCK_DATA (2).csv
[INFO] -   > parsing csv file MOCK_DATA (2).csv of size 62541 
[INFO] - userThread-2  > total users : 2001
[INFO] - userThread-2 > deleting file : MOCK_DATA (1).csv
[INFO] - >Thread is free userThread-2
[INFO] - userThread-1  > saved all 1000 users
[INFO] - userThread-1  > total users : 3001
[INFO] - userThread-1 > deleting file : MOCK_DATA (2).csv
[INFO] - >Thread is free userThread-1
```

---

Below is Controller method:

```
@PostMapping("/")
public ResponseEntity<String> populateTable(@RequestParam MultipartFile files[]) throws Exception {
    log.info("storing files");
    for (MultipartFile f : files) {
        log.info(" -- saving file {}", f.getOriginalFilename());
        File tempFile = new File(f.getOriginalFilename());
        f.transferTo(tempFile.toPath());
        service.saveFile(tempFile);
    }

    log.info("Done processing - sending response back");
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("Populated files");
}
```

---

Below is saveFile method:

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<Integer> saveFile(final File file) throws Exception {
    String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    log.info(threadName + " > processing file {}", file.getName());
    List<User> users = parseCsvFile(file);
    userRepo.saveAll(users);
    log.info(threadName + "  > saved all {} users", users.size());
    log.info(threadName + "  > total users : {}", getUserCount());
    log.info(threadName + " > deleting file : {}", file.getName());
    log.info(">Thread is free: {}", threadName);
    file.delete();
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(users.size());
}
```

---

Below is parseCsvFile method:

```
private List<User> parseCsvFile(final File file) throws Exception {
    final List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    log.info("  > parsing csv file {} of size {} ", file.getName(), file.length());
    try {
        try(final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))){
            String line;
            br.readLine();//skipping first line
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                final String data[] = line.split(",");
                final User u = new User();
                u.setFirstName(data[1]);
                u.setLastName(data[2]);
                u.setEmail(data[3]);
                u.setGender(data[4]);
                u.setIp(data[5]);
                users.add(u);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("  >< something happened");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("  >< something happened with user size {}",
                CollectionUtils.isEmpty(users) ? 0 : users.get(users.size() - 1));
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return users;
}
```